# How to pass an array from php (using json_encode) to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My java script. I want to display image. the javascript require image path as array format. I tried to supply the path throw ajax. its not working. when i use hard code its working. my javascipt below. its not working. the  working code supply below the javascript and my php file code also there.

```
$(function () {
    $.get( "php/building_edit_image_get_db.php", function( your_return_data ) {
    alert(your_return_data);

        $("#editimagefile").fileinput({
            showUpload: false,
            showCaption: false,
            overwriteInitial: true,
            initialPreview: [your_return_data],
            initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
            initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
            browseClass: "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
            allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'png','gif']
        });
    });
});
```

It's not working. when i place hardcode its working properly the script is below

```
$(function () {
    $.get( "php/building_edit_image_get_db.php", function( your_return_data ) {
    alert(your_return_data);

        $("#editimagefile").fileinput({
            showUpload: false,
            showCaption: false,
            overwriteInitial: true,
            initialPreview: [
                "http://lorempixel.com/800/460/people/1",
                "http://lorempixel.com/800/460/people/2"
            ],
            initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
            initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
            browseClass: "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
            allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'png','gif']
        });
    });
});
```

My php file for returing array value.

```
session_start();
require_once ('../aiboc_admin/class/Buidling_Image.php');

$editid = $_SESSION['BUILD_LIST_EDIT_ID'];

$getimgs = Buidling_Image::GetGalleryImageByID($editid);

    foreach ($getimgs as $setimgs)
    {
        $imgs[] = $setimgs['img_url'];
    }
echo json_encode($imgs,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$.parseJSON()` since you're getting json format when you use `json_encode` :

```
$.get( "php/building_edit_image_get_db.php", function( your_return_data ) {

    $("#editimagefile").fileinput({
        showUpload: false,
        showCaption: false,
        overwriteInitial: true,

        initialPreview: $.parseJSON(your_return_data),

        initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
        initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
        browseClass: "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
        allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'png','gif']
    });

});
```

Or you could use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()` request, then you don't need to parse it :

```
$.getJSON( "php/building_edit_image_get_db.php", function( your_return_data ) {
```

Hope this helps.